# Ruby sorting using virtual columns

Tags: sql, ruby, transient

A column in my events table contains a column with values like "Hold", "Important", "Pending", etc.  I want to return query results to a client and sort by this column, but I do not want to sort alphabetically.  "Important" events should be first, "Pending" second, etc. More importantly, I want to return the integer sort value to the client.

```
@work = Transaction.
     joins( :events ).
     where( store_id: params[:work_id] ).
     where( status: 'Open' )
```

Comment: Do you have to add this column? Can't you use some custom sorting algorithm instead?

Comment: I prefer to AVOID adding the column.  The data I need is stored as strings in the "state" column.  And the MySQL FIELD function is my preference to sort.

Comment: MySQL has a built-in `CASE` statement, so you could create a simple function using this, and `ORDER BY` the resulting calculated field. Could you show current Ruby code that sorts by the existing column? It's difficult to give you a Ruby answer without seeing how you are running SQL.

Comment: Currently, the sort is alphabetical by contents of the action field. By the sort is not what I want.  Perhaps this is a better way to ask the question?

Comment: Yes, there is a better way to ask the question: Put your Ruby code that is doing the sort into the question. It doesn't matter that the sort is wrong. If it is too long, try to add just the salient parts. It will be far easier to steer you in the right direction when we can see the structure of the current code.

Comment: @UpperStage may well be using PostgreSQL (or even another database). Don't assume MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
@work = Transaction.
     joins(:events).
     where(store_id: params[:work_id]).
     where(status: 'Open').
     select("(case when your_column = 'Important' then '1' 
                   when your_column = 'Pending' then 2 
                   when your_column = 'Hold' then 3 else 4 end) as your_integer_column").
     order("your_integer_column")
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to return the integer value to the client.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I add a new column without adding it to the table?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question. What we do here is add a virtual database column, which is not actually a persistent database field but just a column in your query results. It than is accessible in your model objects as an attribute and you can access it like, for example, `@work.first.your_integer_column` (gets this value for first object returned by query).

Comment: That's what I did not understand - virtual columns!  Thank you!